Redis Timeseries get last N elements
I have a Redis Timeseries. I want to get the last N (e.g., N=5) elements (i.e., the N elements that have the highest timestamp). How can I do that?
I know that TS.REVRANGE (https://redis.io/docs/latest/commands/ts.revrange/) has a COUNT option, but fromTimestamp and toTimestamp are required, and I don't want to specify a time range.

All you have to do is TS.REVRANGE key - + COUNT 5.
Example:
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.CREATE k
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.MADD k 1 1 k 2 2 k 3 3 k 4 4 k 5 5 k 6 6 k 7 7 k 8 8
1) (integer) 1
2) (integer) 2
3) (integer) 3
4) (integer) 4
5) (integer) 5
6) (integer) 6
7) (integer) 7
8) (integer) 8
127.0.0.1:6379> TS.REVRANGE k - + COUNT 5
1) 1) (integer) 8
   2) 8
2) 1) (integer) 7
   2) 7
3) 1) (integer) 6
   2) 6
4) 1) (integer) 5
   2) 5
5) 1) (integer) 4
   2) 4

